# converting sql into HQL

Tags: hibernate

I am using http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-with-full-hibernate-plugin/ 
as my refernce for struts+hibernate.I need to replace 
"return session.createQuery("from Customer").list();" in CustomerDAOIMPL.java with the following query

```
select u.Loginid,c.CID,CNAME,CTICKER,STOCKVALUE,VARIATE,VARIATE_PERCENT,PREVIOUS_DAY_STOCK,MARKET
from company_details c,users_details u,user_company uc where uc.loginpk=u.loginpk AND uc.CID=c.CID AND uc.loginpk IN (select LOGINPK from users_details where LOGINID="check")
```

how to do write such a query in HQL[Hibernate Query Language] I tried reading my tutorials for google
but nothing go into my mind.Please help me,if possible give the link of tutorial for  creating HQL from SQL involving Joining tables which is very simple to understand

Comment: If you are (completely)new to hibernate, I would recommend, start with converting simple sql to hql and then go for complex one. You'll definitely find those tutorial helpful. Besides for this sql, show your beans & mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are beginner, go through these simple example's link:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm
- <strike>http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/HqlTutorial</strike> ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170527141302/http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/HqlTutorial))

For more reference :
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html